# Cell conditional formatting, based on the format of the same row's cells of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I've highlighted my duplicate text in column B, using Conditional Formatting. No I want to highlight the same field on column A (and afterwards delete all non highlighted texts), but I am not sure how to do it.

At this time, my excel file is like this:

[image: now]

and the expected result after this task is to have it like this one:

[image: my goal]

Comment: Just select your table and filter your column B (By color), once done delete the rows.

Comment: im not sure if this will end up matching my goal. Im on excel 2016 if it helps btw!

Comment: My goal is to have all entries of the same row of the column A hightlighted aswell

Comment: Ths can be done using a VBA code

Comment: Can you please share this code?

Answer (score 1):

In this example the sample data is in Cells D2:E7.
Now you have already applied Conditional Formatting to Column E based on Duplicate Values. Make a note of the color or select a color from Custom Format.

Now in D2 put the following Conditional Formatting Rule. You have to select Formula this time.

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$7,E2)>1
```

Apply the same color that you opted earlier for Column E. Click OK and the using Format Painter apply the Formatting to rest of the cells in Column D.

[image]

Now your matching values shall be highlighted.

[image]

Now put a Filter on First Row. If you have a header select it else the first row of the table. Better to have a Header row to your data.

Now Filter by Color and No Fill. So all non duplicates will be shown and Duplicates shall be filtered. Select the rows and Delete.

[image]

[image]

Update: How to use Format Painter

---

After you have applied the Conditional Formatting Formula Rule to A1, click on A1 and go to Format Painter on Home Tab

Click the format painter. Now it will be attached to the cursor.

Now Click and Hold on A2 and just Drag it down up to the intended rows. The Formatting shall get applied to all applicable cells.

[image]

See the below sample animation on how to use Format Painter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I've added =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$50,B1)>1 to a new rule and I ended up in an error "there is a problem with this forula"

Comment: May be the List Separator in your Regional Settings is ; instead of , i.e. Semicolon instead of Comma. Try using ; therein

Comment: FYR... Windows --> Control Panel --> Region and Language --> Additional Setting --> List Separator. You have to change the formula to =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$50;B1)>1 in that case.

Comment: It worked now with no errors, but cells of A column are not hightlighted.

Comment: Did you apply this rule first to only A1 and then used the Format Painter to apply it to all other applicable cells of Column A ?

Comment: I went to A1 and applied this =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$50;B1)>1 - then I formated the A1 to the same format like my B's. Im not sure how this will be applied to the rest?

Comment: Do not apply formatting from B to A now. See the update in my above answer and use format painter as described and confirm if it worked or not.

Comment: Im stuck much more before this step. My A column entries are not getting highlighted, even if I use your steps for the format.

Comment: Before applying to your actual data in Cols A & B, can you just try to simulate this in another test sheet with just a few sample rows like what you have shown in the screenshots?

Comment: Thanks for the patience :) I did what you suggested and ended up into a non highlighted entries of A column. Heres my actions: http://prntscr.com/lpk5vy

Comment: Your Conditional Formatting Formula in test example for cell A1 should be =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5;B1)>1 you are starting with B2 thru B5 instead.

Comment: I tried pure filtering and sorted things out. Copied all sorted data to a new sheet and its done. Thanks for the overall help. It was really a great one. Im now trying to remove duplicates but I opened up a new question for this, since my tries fail: https://superuser.com/questions/1380096/keep-only-one-copy-of-the-duplicated-data