# Keep only one copy of the duplicated data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to clear out a list of content that appears 2,3,4 or more times repeatedly.

I have two columns and I would like to eliminate the whole row of any repeatedly entry of column B.

My current sheet can be shown here:

[image: screenshot 1]

and after the needed trick, it should be shown like this:

[image: screenshot 2]

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

(Out of my head, untested): In C2, enter

```
 =IF(B2=B1;"x";"")
```

and copy this down to all cells in row C. This gives you an "x" for each duplicate value in column B. Now, you can set an auto filter to A-C, select all marked rows and delete them.

If you want to remove non-consecutive duplicates, the most simple approach is to sort the columns A-B first by B, using Excel's sorting feature. And if you want to preserve the order, first fill a helper column (for example, D) with numbers 1,2,3,..., then sort A-D by B, fill C with the formula above, delete the marked duplicates and then sort A-D by D to restore the original order.

See [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3421-excel-delete-rows-based-on-duplicates-in-one-column.html)  for another method using Excel's "Remove Duplicate" feature.

Comment: Its not working as expected for me. It understands immediatelly duplicated valued, but not repeated valued after some rows: http://prntscr.com/lq9vgq

Comment: @JohnGreco: of course it does not - your example does not contain such kind of duplicates, so I was only answering to what you asked, nothing else. But see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write this Array Formula in Cell `E112`, finish with `ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$112:$B$117, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$111:E111, $B$112:$B$117), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this Formula in Cell `D112` & fill down.

  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$112:$A$117,MATCH(E112,$B$112:$B$117,0)),"")`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks for the usefull answer, however, I have an issue at last step: http://prntscr.com/lpoerv

Comment: @John Greco,, what error or problem you have been facing since  both formula worked properly,,, my screen shot is part of active sheet !!

Comment: It is not allowing me to enter the forumal. I pasted a URL in the previous reply, which shows the issue, straight from my excel file

Comment: The error was because you were missing brackets {} in the second Forumal. I added them but still, no luck. I took  a screenshot, if it helps: https://prnt.sc/lq81vh

Comment: @JohnGreco,, second formula isn't an array formula so that it doesn't needs {} ,,, actually you don't have value in Range `E112:E115` . Your screen shot shows only the first formula in `E112`. Better execute the first formula properly,, you find the second one working !!

Comment: @JohnGreco,, check the screen shot attached with the answer is part of active sheet the genuine data!!